# Use Beam files to start an application in Elixir

Tags: configuration, elixir, elixir-mix

I am working on Elixir project where i have to register three dependencies say "xxx, yyy & zzz" for the project. I have done deps.get on those repositories and compiled that. But, i checked after compilation no ".app" file is generated for xxx dependency but only beam files. yyy & zzz got compiled with .app files and application got started as well. So, Can i use generated/compiled xxx beam files in mix.exs anyhow to start an application for xxx dependency.Application is defined like below in mix.exs file,

```
def application do
[applications: [:yyy, :xxx, :zzz],
 mod: {Practice, []}]
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the application has no app file, you do not need to specify it in the applications list as you did in your code snippet. Instead just pass `app: false` as an option where the dependency is defined.

PS: Please don't double post your issues on Stack Overflow and in the Elixir mailing list. Pick one as both are checked regularly by many developers in the community.